# Merging different answers into one 'better' one

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Sometimes I find that there's good points in different answers (and comments), so I wonder if it's okay to create my own answer (if I'm the one who originally asked the question) based on those, and accept it. Here's [an example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3568/how-to-switch-between-users-on-one-terminal) where I'm tempted to do so.

Answer (score 3):

It's generally fine depending on the circumstances, although it's probably not necessary on that question, since there's only two answers. I'd upvote both (disclamer: one of them is mine :) ), and accept whichever one you actually ended up using (looks like you already did that part).

There's a [main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7008/why-isnt-there-a-way-to-consolidate-answers) about consolidating answers; it looks like the opinion there was to take the best answer and merge in parts of other answers if you like, rather than creating a whole new answer; you're welcome to merge my answer into the accepted answer if you like

Comment: Of course, you need a certain amount of rep to do that...

Comment: Which I recently got :) and soon to lose (we are launching soon)

Comment: @Tshepang Oh yeah, that's too bad. Get another 1k in the next day or two :)